# Using filepath without getting utf5 error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, spyder

Following code line produces an `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 57-58: malformed \N character escape`:

```
self.le1 = QLineEdit('\\S24014\\file.xlsx', self)
```

This is a filepath, that I Need to Keep.
Spyder Shows that `\\S24014` is the Problem. The file has `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top. How to solve the Problem?

I am using Spyder 2 with Python 3.5 and PyQt4

Comment: Is your string supposed to have any escaped characters in it or is it supposed to be literally `\\S24014\\file.xlsx`? If the latter, what happens if you pass it as a raw string i.e. `r'\\S24014\\file.xlsx`?

Comment: This helped :-), thanks! Yes, the `\\S24014` path must stay.

Comment: Cool, I've posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you need to pass the string as a [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), i.e. `r'\\S24014\\file.xlsx`.

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
>   letter `r` or `R`; such strings are called *raw strings* and treat
>   backslashes as literal characters.